# Button to run a script AND open a web page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a button on my classic google site, that when pressed will run a script I have written.  The script will either create a page or amend the html if it already exists.  As I am using the 'button' to run the script, how do I show amended/created page?

From researching this, it appears that you cannot show a webpage using the script.  That suggests that I would need to have the page linked to the button, but I am using that to run the script.

I am new to javascript and HTML, so my apologies if this should be obvious.  The only thing I can think of is that the user would need to press the button to update the page and then press another link generated by the script when the updating was complete.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: for the button in the `onclick` try to separate the 2 actions by `;`. So would be `<input type="button" onclick="google.script.run.myFunction;window.open()"` (note, not actual code for the onclick.

Comment: Thanks for that Vytautas, but I can't get Google sites HTML to do this.  It strips out the code.